# How to Fix `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 3` for Passing data from Vue to Iframe?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I've got a problem with decoding my JSON which it was kinda different since I'm using Vue Component to pass array to iFrame element. I tried suggestion and solutions from some answer of stack but didn't worked for me.

Here's the error :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 3`

So Vue part :

```
<iframe :src="getMultipleMarkers()"></iframe>

getMultipleMarkers(){
    var markers = [this.reports];
        console.log(markers[0])
        return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/multipleMarakers.html?reports=${JSON.stringify(markers[0])}`;
}
```

Html file :

```
var params = location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
data = [];
for (x in params)
{
    data[params[x].split('=')[0]] = params[x].split('=')[1];
}

console.log(JSON.parse(data['reports']));
```

And Here's the responses i received in HTML file without `Json.Parse`

```
[{%22id%22:108,%22employe_id%22:4,%22method%22:%22online%22,%22status%22:%22none%22,%22lat%22:31.284921666666666,%22lng%22:48.73399666666666,%22received_date%22:%2205:42:51%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22received_date_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:42:51%22,%22created_at%22:%2205:42:51%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22created_at_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:42:51%22},{%22id%22:107,%22employe_id%22:4,%22method%22:%22online%22,%22status%22:%22none%22,%22lat%22:31.284921666666666,%22lng%22:48.73399666666666,%22received_date%22:%2205:37:57%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22received_date_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:37:57%22,%22created_at%22:%2205:37:57%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22created_at_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:37:57%22},{%22id%22:106,%22employe_id%22:4,%22method%22:%22online%22,%22status%22:%22none%22,%22lat%22:31.284921666666666,%22lng%22:48.73399666666666,%22received_date%22:%2205:27:58%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22received_date_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:27:58%22,%22created_at%22:%2205:27:58%20-%201398-09-17%22,%22created_at_original%22:%222019-12-08%2005:27:58%22},{%22id%22:11,%22employe_id%22:4,%22method%22:%22online%22,%22status%22:%22none%22,%22lat%22:31.2849217,%22lng%22:48.7339967,%22received_date%22:%2215:48:18%20-%201398-09-16%22,%22received_date_original%22:%222019-12-07%2015:48:18%22,%22created_at%22:%2215:48:18%20-%201398-09-16%22,%22created_at_original%22:%222019-12-07%2015:48:18%22}]
```

Also in this picture i've consoled array in vue component and HTML file, which in first response u'll see they array and i'm sending this to iframe which It's getting responses with "%22" characters. i don't know how should i fix this issue or how should i replace all these %22 to ".

[image]

Here's the data in array in picture at 0 index:

```
created_at: "05:42:51 - 1398-09-17"
created_at_original: "2019-12-08 05:42:51"
employe_id: 4
id: 108
lat: 31.284921666666666
lng: 48.73399666666666
method: "online"
received_date: "05:42:51 - 1398-09-17"
received_date_original: "2019-12-08 05:42:51"
status: "none"
```

[image]

I also tried to replace %22 with ", but it was only replacing first one, and when i used map function i was getting error. tried new Array and other things. so please help me to fix this issue.

Edit 01 : i'm getting null in console in html part.

```
var params = location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
data = [];
for (x in params)
{
    data[params[x].split('=')[0]] = params[x].split('=')[1];
}
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
const reports = JSON.parse(queryParams.get(data['reports']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `getMultipleMarkers` a computed property instead of a method. It'll be [much more efficient](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods). Also, I have no idea why you're wrapping `this.reports` in a `markers` array and only ever accessing `markers[0]` so you might as well just refer to `this.reports`.
2. Encode your query parameters properly with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

   ```js
   computed: {
     iframeSrc () {
       return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/multipleMarakers.html?reports=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.reports))}`
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <iframe :src="iframeSrc" />
   ```

   Note that the computed property is **not** used like a function ie, it's `iframeSrc` and not `iframeSrc()`.
3. In your *"Html file"*, use `location.search` to get at the query string and [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to clean up the keys and values. You can find an example here ~ https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript (scroll down to the **JavaScript Fallback** part)

   Even easier is [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (if your [target browsers support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility))

   ```js
   const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
   const reports = JSON.parse(queryParams.get('reports'))
   ```

Comment: @Atlas-Pio I've updated my answer. You should be using `:src="getMultipleMarkers"` if it's a computed property, **not** `:src="getMultipleMarkers()"`

Comment: @Atlas-Pio I added a link for reading and decoding URL query parameters. Does that not work for you?

Comment: no. it's worked, i had a mistake and your solution worked. i'm trying to understand the html part. looks like you searched in location parameters then get data['reports'] with 'reports' because it was in url, so base on what u said i can just get my array like this and no need to my other methods from before, am i right?